# changing width of dropdown control in MVC marked by Chosen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdown, jquery-chosen

I have regular dropdown control in mvc. I want to decorate it with [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), I have seen the API in their [official website](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). It's as

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({width: "95%"});
```

Even with plain dropdown it's width remains unchanged. Help Please.

Answer (score 0):

I have written like below and worked for me.

## CSS

```
<link href="~/Content/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

## Html

```
  @Html.DropDownList("naicsCodeSelect", ViewBag.selectCodes as List<SelectListItem>, new { @multiple = "true", @class = "chosen-select" })
```

## Javascript

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".chosen-select").chosen({width: "95%"});            
    });
  </script>
```

## Update

if the above code does not work then use the below style

```
<style>
    .chosen-container
     {
       width:95%!important;
     }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

On [their demo site](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), the 95% width example defines the following:

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" title="" style="width: 95%;">
   <a class="chosen-single">
    .
    .
```

Your chosen dropdown should have the same application.  If you inspect the source, can you confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

The chosen() plugin determines the size of the searchable dropdowns by reading the select's outerWidth property. Unfortunately, the calculated width is just a little to narrow for a proper display. The easiest way to adjust the width is to change the size of the select field's outerWidth property. The following code will do this for you:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // change field_g69s05 to your field's ID

    $("#field_g69s05").outerWidth(230);

});
```

**Hope this is helpful :)**

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$('.chosen-choices').css("width", "50px");
```

or

```
$('.chosen-choices').css("width", "50%");
```